# ([facebook-analytics])-Track other pages in the website using Facebook Analytics

Tags: facebook-analytics

I have a website maybe is www.jaminebaker.com and there is a feedback page and a article page. In my article page, there is also a share button to Facebook. Can I check whether is it possible for Facebook Analytics to trace whether did I click on the feedback page also ? I know that I can track the Facebook share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally possible. If you're using Facebook Pixel, check [this](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755) out. If you're using the Facebook Analytics JS SDK, check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent) out.